# Microsoft Access Script Control

Tags: ms-access, scriptcontrol

where can I find this script control on microsoft access? i can't find it in the design tab. I need this so that I can use this code

Scriptcontrol1.Eval(x)

i need to use a string to convert it as a Vba statement.

Comment: Access has its own `Eval()` function, have you tried that?

Comment: yes it has but i need scriptcontrol. eval() function doesnt read this line, Dim a as Integer Dim b as Integer Dim c as String a = 1 b = 2 c = "a + b" MsgBox Eval(c)            it has error after that